# Quit the program when catching error in C#?

Tags: c#, exception, exit

With Python, I normally check the return value. And, if there's an error, I use `sys.exit()` together with error message.

What's equivalent action in C#?

- Q1 : How to print out an error message to stderr stream?
- Q2 : How to call system.exit() function in C#?
- Q3 : Normally, how C# programmers process the errors? Raising and catching exceptions? Or, just get the return value and exit()?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Q1: In C#, you have to use System.Console.xxx in order to access the streams for input, output, and error: System.Console.Error is the standard error you can write to.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.aspx

Q2: You exit with:

```
System.Environment.Exit( exitCode );
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx

Q3: Yes, C# programmers raise (throw) exceptions (objects of classes deriving from the Exception class), and catch them in upper-level callers.

If you want to catch errors in the entire program, you just encapsulate the entire main() procedure in a try...catch:

```
class App {
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            <your code here>
        } catch(Exception exc) {
            <exception handling here>
        }
        finally {
            <clean up, when needed, here>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not use `System.Environment.Exit`. Sure it's cool you can kill your app whenever you want but doing so makes automated testing of your code more difficult than it needs to be.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, you simply don't catch exceptions you can't handle. .NET takes care of killing your process for you.